# Error assigning values to the nested map with tuple as its value

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, stdmap, stdtuple

I been maintaining some statistics in a map, the below are my typedefs to create the map

```
typedef Time TOTALTIME,MINM,MAXM,AVRG;
typedef std::map<std::string,std::map<status,int>> RequestStatus;//status is an enum
typedef std::tuple<int,TOTALTIME,MINM,MAXM,AVRG,RequestStatus> Attributes ;
typedef std::map<std::string,Attributes> requestStatistics ;
```

`requestStatistics sampleStruct`  //my final map

And i have been initializing like

```
sampleStruct.insert(make_pair(someskey,std::make_tuple(1,TOTALTIME(),MINM(),MAXM(),AVRG(),sampleStatus[functionName][status::READY]=1)));
```

other way I have tried

```
sampleStruct[somekey]=std::make_tuple(1,TOTALTIME(),MINM(),MAXM(),AVRG(),sampleStatus[functionName][status::READY]=1)
```

Both doesn't pass the compiler always endup in compile error, lemme put out some compile error I,ve got

```
     std::map<endstor::Data::statistics::status, int, std::less<endstor::Data::statistics::status>, std::allocator<std::pair<const endstor::Data::statistics::status, int> > >,
std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::map<endstor::Data::statistics::status, int, std::less<endstor::Data::statistics::status>, std::allocator<std::pair<const endstor::Data::statistics::status, int> > > > > > > > >]
             insert(const_iterator __position, _Pair&& __x)
```

1)was the structure I've created is valid?were the assignments are ok?

Comment: The error you have included looks to be related to an instance of `RequestStatus` not `requestStatistics`.  Please edit your question to contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter in your `insert` or `make_tuple` calls is `sampleStatus[functionName][status::READY]=1`, which is an `int`, while the tuple is expecting a `RequestStatus`.  This type difference would be the cause of your error.